# Is there something I'm doing wrong in my nested if statements?

Tags: c#

When I enter values in my form I receive no output in my `lowestNumberLabel`. I do receive a message box if numbers are the same value but nothing else. I'm not sure what's wrong so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        double firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber;

        firstNumber = double.Parse(firstNumberTextBox.Text);
        secondNumber = double.Parse(secondNumberTextBox.Text);
        thirdNumber = double.Parse(thirdNumberTextBox.Text);

        if (firstNumber == secondNumber)
        {
            if (firstNumber == thirdNumber)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("All the numbers are equal");
            }
            else if (firstNumber < secondNumber)
            {
                if (firstNumber < thirdNumber)
                {
                    lowestNumberLabel.Text = firstNumber.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    lowestNumberLabel.Text = secondNumber.ToString();
                }
                {
                    if (secondNumber < thirdNumber)
                    {
                        lowestNumberLabel.Text = secondNumber.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lowestNumberLabel.Text = thirdNumber.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter values correctly");
    }
}

private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstNumberTextBox.Text = "";
    secondNumberTextBox.Text = "";
    thirdNumberTextBox.Text = "";
    lowestNumberLabel.Text = "";
}

private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: The only issue here is that you need to learn how to step through your code with the debugger and inspect the variables, do you know how to do this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows?view=vs-2019

Comment: `if (firstNumber == secondNumber)` What do you suppose happens if they are *not* equal?

Comment: You should provide some details about some special cases, for example these two cases (3, 3, 5) and (5, 7, 7).

Comment: Consider re-wording the title of your question.  It not only helps today's readers but also those in the future trying to find answers via search engines.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I created a List so I could use the .Min method.

```
    private void Calculate()
    {
        List<double> lst = new List<double>();

        lst.Add(Double.Parse(firstNumberTextBox.Text));
        lst.Add(Double.Parse(secondNumberTextBox.Text));
        lst.Add(Double.Parse(thirdNumberTextBox.Text));
       
        if (lst[0] == lst[1] && lst[1] == lst[2])
            MessageBox.Show("All the numbers are equal");
        else
            lowestNumberLabel.Text = lst.Min().ToString();
    }
```